# Optimal p and q for ARMA (p, q)-eGARCH (1,1) model

Tags: r

Here is my question:
I want to find out the optimal p and q for my ARMA (p, q)-eGARCH (1,1) where p, q are ranging from 0 to 5. Then I select the model with smallest AIC value. But sometimes there are the warning:

```
In arima(data, order = c(modelinc[2], 0, modelinc[3]), include.mean = modelinc[1],  :
  possible convergence problem: optim gave code = 1
```

So is there any way that I can set the output equal to +10000 if the warning occurs? Is there anything like try, except of Python in R?

Comment: Check out [try](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/try.html) and [tryCatch](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/conditions.html)

Comment: ok thanks you so much